# Does drug resistant cancer eventually lose its drug resistance?

Tags: cancer, genetics, resistance

Does a cancer cell population eventually lose its drug resistance, if you give it enough time? For example, if you take some cancer cells in vitro, make them drug resistant to a certain drug, then wait two years - what percent is still resistant? How quickly does genetic drift cause it to lose the resistance?

Are there any papers on this? I could not find any.

Comment: AFAIK no - try looking for loss of drug resistance in cell cultures; it might give you more luck. Note that it would be totally unethical to leave a cancer untreated just to try and make it drug sensitive again...

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.